# How do I utilize supportsNullCreation() in Jersey?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have an injectable provider that may or may return null.  I am getting an exception when it is null.  I registered the provider as a Singleton, can I possibly register it as a type of SingletonContext that I customize to return true for supportsNullCreation()?  I think if I can do that then even if findOrCreate() returns null, my code will still run which is what I want.

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig 
{
    public MyApplication()
    {
        ...
    // Provider of DB
    this.register( new AbstractBinder()
    {
       @Override
       public void configure()
       {
 bindFactory(DbManager.class).to(EntityManagerFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
       }
    });
}
```

Then it is used like this:

```
@Singleton
@Path("myservice")
public class WebServiceClass
{
   // NOTE: Right now I have to comment this to run without a DB
   @Inject
   private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
   ...
```

The exception I get is this...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context 
 org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext@6cae5847 findOrCreate returned a null for 
descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.db.DbManager
    contracts={javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=PROVIDE_METHOD
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@7050f2b1
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=145
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=863132354
    reified=true)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2075)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend changing the design a bit. Using the `EntityManagerFactory` in the resource class is not very great design. You are left with code like

```
public class Resource {
    private EntityManagerFctory emf;

    @POST
    public Response get(Entity e) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(e);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

There are a lot of things wrong with this picture. For one you are breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle][1]. Secondly this doesn't allow you to elegantly handle the `null` EMF, even if it was possible. You have this all over the place

```
if (emf != null) {
    // do code above
} else {
    // do something else.
}
```

Also it is no great for testing. The common pattern is to use a [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) layer. Personally I even add a service layer in between the DAO and the REST layer, but you can get away with just a DAO layer.

For example what I would do is create a common abstraction interface for the data access calls.

```
public interface DataService {
    Data getData();
}
```

Then create an implementation for db access

```
public class WithDbService implements DataService {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public WithDbService(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    @Override
    public Data getData() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then create another implementation without db access.

```
public class WithoutDbService implements DataService {
    @Override
    public Data getData() {}
}
```

Then you can use a `Factory` to create the `DataService`. What you will do is use the `ServiceLocator` to try and find the EMF. If it is not null, return the `WithDbService` else return the `WithoutDbService`

```
public class DataServiceFatory implements Factory<DataService> {

    private DataService dataService;

    @Inject
    public DataServiceFactory(ServiceLocator locator) {
        // abbreviated for brevity
        EMF emf = locator.getService(EMF.class);
        if (emf != null) {
            dataService = new WithDbService(emf);
        } else {
            dataService = new WithoutDbService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DataService provider() { return dataService; }
}
[...]
bindFactory(DataServiceFactory.class).to(DataService.class).in(..);
```

Then you can just inject `DataService` every where. As long as the two implementations follow the contract, it should work just fine.

There may be some design improvements, but it is a big step up from using the EMF directly in the resource class.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That solved the problem completely, and much better design as well.